# Upload file to Windows Azure with only the link of the file is provided

Tags: javascript, azure, dropbox, azure-storage, dropbox-api

How can I upload a file in azure if I only have the URL of the file to upload. In this case, i 'm using [Dropbox file chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) which selects file from dropbox and returns its url path.
eq

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9myet72y19iaan/Getting%20Started.pdf

Now we need the file to be stored in Windows Azure blob. What is the easiest way to do this without downloading the file first.
I'm planning to use a asp.net web api for the uploading of file to azure blob.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought it should be quite straight forward as Azure Blob Storage support copying blobs from external URL however I don't think this would work in case of Dropbox files. I just tried it and got an error even though.

The link you mentioned above is not the direct link to the file. It's a link to a page on Dropbox's website from where you can download a file. This is obviously you don't want. Here's an alternate solution which you can try:

Replace `www.dropbox.com` in your URL with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` (based on @smarx's comments below) and use that URL in the following code:

<del>First you would need to append `dl=1` to your request URL as query string. So your Dropbox URL would be `https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9myet72y19iaan/Getting%20Started.pdf?dl=1`. `dl` query string parameter indicates the file needs to be downloaded.</del>

<del>Next, using `HTTPWebRequest` try accessing this URL. Dropbox will respond back with another link and `302` status code. This link would be something like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/o9myet72y19iaan/Getting%20Started.pdf?token_hash=<tokenhash>`.</del>

<del>Use this link in the code below to copy file. This would work.</del>

```
        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account", "key"), false);
        var client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("dropbox-file-name");
        blob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri("dropbox URL with dl.dropboxusercontent.com"));
        Console.WriteLine("Copy request accepted");
        Console.WriteLine("Now checking for copy state");
        bool continueLoop = true;
        do
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            var copyState = blob.CopyState;
            switch (copyState.Status)
            {
                case CopyStatus.Pending:
                    Console.WriteLine("Copy is still pending. Will check status again after 1 second.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);//Copy is still pending...check after 1 second
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Terminating process with copy state = " + copyState.Status);
                    continueLoop = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (continueLoop);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
```

Comment: No need to do do the redirect thing. You can just replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/53/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links.

Comment: @Gaurav I am using asp.net web api - do I just need to create a POST method and just post the url? somthing like Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadPdf(string url) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you would do. Thanks @smarx for the pointer. I have updated my answer.