# How can I upload a file in azure if I only have the URL of the file to upload in NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, blob

How can I upload a file in azure if I only have the URL of the file to upload. In this case, i 'm using Dropbox file chooser which selects file from dropbox and returns its url path. eq

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9myet72y19iaan/Getting%20Started.pdf

Now we need the file to be stored in Windows Azure blob. What is the easiest way to do this without downloading the file first. I'm planning to use a asp.net web api for the uploading of file to azure blob.

I am working on same issue. I have direct download link but Iam working on NodeJS.

Can anyone help in coding in nodeJS ? As i am new to node JS...

Please have a look at the issue
[Upload file to Windows Azure with only the link of the file is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484650/upload-file-to-windows-azure-with-only-the-link-of-the-file-is-provided/27357091#27357091)

Comment: Have you taken a look at node.js SDK for Azure Storage - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node? Look for `Copy Blob` there.

Comment: i am not able to find copy blob. Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/legacyStorage/lib/blob/blobservice.js#L1762. HTH.

Comment: Got it. Will check it out and let u know

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer (and accepting it)? It might help somebody else.

Comment: working for me also ;)